# wkhtmltopdf in python script is not working with cronjob

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04, wkhtmltopdf

I am getting the below error while running python script as cronjob. But its working while executing manually.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 21, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 626, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 621, in main

  File "/home/ubuntu/aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 95, in html_to_pdf

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 47, in from_file
    configuration=configuration, cover_first=cover_first)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.configuration = (Configuration() if configuration is None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 27, in __init__
    'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

The file `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` is executable and paths are exported by default.

```
root@jump-box:/home/ubuntu# whereis wkhtmltopdf
wkhtmltopdf: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

root@jump-box:/home/ubuntu# which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

root@jump-box:/home/ubuntu# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Any guess on what could be the issue?

Comment: Looks like `self.wkhtmltopdf`is an empty bytestring... now why is it the case and what should it be, we can't tell without more informations. Perhaps a [mcve] could help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add this job:

```
 * * * * * echo $PATH >> /ws/tmp.log 2>&1
```

then:

```
> cat tmp.log
/usr/bin:/bin
```

So you probably want to wrap your cronjob in a script that sets up the environment properly

Comment: Thanks @Jonah `/usr/local/bin` was not showing with cron. I have fixed it by adding PATH in crontab.